# Change what attributes are returned from Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item::getProduct()

Tags: product-attribute, quoteitem

Really the title explains it!

I'm trying to perform some extra checks on products in the cart, however in order to do so I need to grab some extra attributes from the product.

Calling

```
 $item->getProduct()
```

only returns a small subset of the product's attributes, and doesn't include what I need.

At the moment, I'm re-loading the product using

```
 Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
```

but this seems a really in-efficient way of doing it.

Is there a way to add extra attributes to the

```
 $item->getProduct()
```

call without extending the class method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use magento collections and specify which attributes to load, try this:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $productId)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('some_attribute')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('one_more_attribute');
```

Comment: Hi @lloiacono - that's essentially what I am doing at the moment, except I am using load(). The question was more if there was a way to avoid loading the product twice.

Comment: When you use load it will get everything, if you want to get just the attributes you need then you should do it with collections, as far as I know there is no other way to prevent loading twice. But you could replace the first load with the collection load, this way you are loading the product only once with the information you need